# Word order in defining and non-defining relative clauses

Tags: word-order, relative-clauses

With defining relative clauses, there is a different word order according to the status of the relative pronoun in the sentence (that is, it can be either the subject or the object of the relative clause).

> 1. The relative pronoun is the subject. The word order is --> subject + verb + object
> 2. The relative pronoun is the object. The word order is --> object + subject + verb

Does this rule apply to the non-defining relative clauses as well? Or is there any other rule to follow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There doesn’t seem to be any difference between the word order in defining and non-defining relative clauses, as these examples suggest:

Defining, relative pronoun as subject:
*This is the man who built the house.* (SVO)

Defining, relative pronoun as object: *This is the man whom I love.* (OVS)

Non-defining, relative pronoun as subject:
*Jack, who is 32 next month, built that house.* (SVO)

Non-defining, relative pronoun as object:
*Jack, whom my sister married three years ago, built that house.* (OVS)